# Is replacing PNGs with JPGs the solution to generating reliable images in PDF files?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, png, print-to-pdf

I generated a PDF from a document that contains many images, mostly JPGs, but some PNGs.

In the doc (Libre Office .odt), the page in question looks like this:

[image]

When I "exported" the document to a PDF, that page appears like this:

[image]

Flummoxed, I copied the image from the .odt file and pasted it into Paint. I then selected File > Save to see what image type it defaulted to. It was PNG. So, on a hunch, I saved it as a JPG. I replaced the PNG file in the .odt file with the new JPG. I generated a new PDF. The image now generates correctly.

Was this a fluke, or are JPGs more reliable/the preferred image type for use in documents that will be PDFerized?

### UPDATE

I replaced six images that were goofed up like this; they were all PNGs until I saved them as JPGs and then replaced the original PNGs with JPGs. On re-generating (exporting) as PDf, all problems were solved.

I did notice too, though, that at least one of the images was quite large (13 MB). I used Irfanview to "halve" it, which took it down to 2.3 MB; I then halved *that* image, which brought it down to about 690KB. It still looked fine at the size I needed.

Comment: You've got a [print-to-pdf] tag.  Did you create the PDF by using a PDF printer driver, or the LO Writer Export to PDF?  It's possible that the PDF conversion utility was the problem (it looks like it got indigestion from the pixel density of the image and didn't properly relate it to the image size).  Whichever way you generated the PDF, try it the other way and see what you get (if you exported to PDF, load a print-to-pdf driver if you don't have one.  Also, try using one of the free web conversion services on the file.  (cont'd)

Comment: It's also possible that LO is the problem.  If you have access to Word, or say Google Doc, see what happens if you convert the file to .docx and then convert to PDF from that (if the problem is how LO stores it in the .odt, subsequent conversion to .docx may be too late to change it).  It may also be fixable by resizing the image before embedding it in LO.

Comment: You might find this informative: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/04/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-how-are-images-stored/

Comment: Another option to test: Microsoft Office Online is free: https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/documents-spreadsheets-presentations-office-online?rtc=1.  Go to Word, upload your .odt document and save it there as a PDF.  See if that has the problem.

Comment: @fixer1234: I used Libre Office's File > Export as PDF...